# Valores checkbox em sessão de array como string

Tags: array, string, int

Pretendo juntar num *array* os valores de um *checkbox* mas como *string* e de forma a que fiquem separados por `array('string1','string2')`, para poder usar numa consulta mysql `IN('string1','string2')`.

Estes valores vêm de um checkbox para uma sessão:

```
$variavel= $_SESSION['checkbox'] = implode(',',$_POST['checkbox']);
```

Desta forma, ele separa apenas os valores com `,`, `array(int1,int2)`, mas quando junto um valor *string* ele dá erro.

Como poderei juntar ' a cada valor na array para ficar assim `array('string1','string2')`?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, achei uma solução, que até pode nem ser a mais correta, mas que funcionou direitinho através do valor do checkbox, onde apenas concatenei o hiffen antes e depois ao resultado.

Se houver uma solução mais pro para esta situação, agradeço a ajuda e/ou esclarecimento.

o meu checkbox:

```
<input name="chekcbox[]" type="checkbox" id="chekcbox" value="<?php echo "'".$linhaQueryMySql['campo']."'"; ?>" <?php if(strpos($variavel1,$linhaQueryMySql['campo'])!== false) echo 'checked="checked"'?> />
```